# Extracting the middle part of a URL and appending it to a new external link to display in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, slice

I'm having some difficulty making a simple function to take a portion (a variable number of characters) of a URL and append it to another URL then display it.

Here's the kicker - it must work on IE8.

I'm currently using the following code in HTML with Javascript to append text input to a URL, but I would like to automate the process by having user input be the entire URL and extracting a part of it to the end of the base URL. I am currently using HTML and Javascript for open to suggestions on how to handle it cleanly in a method which will function correctly on IE8

Example of original URL - http://www.website.com/search?type=165498746&otheroperator?type=168574981&search?type=165498746&display

Example of part I need to extract - 165498746 (the first occurrence, directly after search?type=)

Example of complete URL to display - http://www.website.com/file?type=165498746

Javascript:

`function ChangeLink() {
    var inputlink = document.getElementById("userinputtext");
    var baselink = document.getElementById("baseurl");
    baselink.href = ("http://www.website.com/search?type=" + inputlink.value);
    baselink.innerHTML = baselink.href;
}`

HTML:
`<form>
<a id="baseurl" href="http://www.website.com">www.website.com</a>
   <input type="text" id="userinputtext" size="20">
   <input type="button" value="Generate Profile Link" name="generate" onClick="ChangeLink()">
</form>`

Noteworthy is that the part of the text I need to append to the end of the link will originate from the middle of the original link, and also that the original url may change in length of characters as will the actual portion I wish to append to the URL.

The only part which is consistent is that the part I wish to extract is after the initial "search?type=" and the ampersand directly after that, but both "search?type=" and the ampersand may appear more than once in the URL.

I have tried to slice() the text, but as the length of the portion I wish to slice varies in length I have been unable to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get the indexOf('?');
2. Get the substring from indexOf('?') to the end of the string.
3. String.split('&')
4. iterate through split.

   - For each split item, split it again on "="
   - First item of split is the name of the parameter.
   - Second item of the split is the value.
   - Check if it is the name of the parameter you are looking for or whatever you want.

Comment: Will explore this option a bit today, it's very similar to what I tried to do in the past and was unsuccessful due to what I assumed were limitations in IE8.

Comment: split and indexOf of are pretty standard js functions and should be supported back to ie6.

Comment: It's **very** possible it may not have worked due to an error on my part, but I do recall running into some issues where the code would work well on other browsers and just not output on IE. I suppose another thing worth mentioning is that it would be for use in company computers, which are on internet security properties dictated outside of my department.   I will definitely give it another shot though.

Comment: As it turns this does work on IE8, but it does not work with the security settings set for javascript by our IT department. As this was the correct answer for a problem such as mine without taking into account problems specific to me, I'll accept it.

Comment: Can you specify what security settings prevent this?  Would be good to know for future reference.